# Prevent Angular $watch from looping

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch, angularjs-digest

I am in the process of putting together a quick money input that automatically adds the decimal point to the amount that is entered. However I am running into a problem where my $watch function is looping forever and then errors. This is what I have:

```
$scope.$watch('enteredBillAmount.number', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
        $scope.enteredBillAmount.number = Number(newValue) / 100;
    }
});
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your watch function changes the item you're watching, so of course it's going to loop. Every time the function runs it triggers the watch.

You can do one of two things, either use a different variable for the number:

```
$scope.$watch('enteredBillAmount.number', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
        $scope.enteredBillAmountNumber = Number(newValue) / 100;
    }
});
```

But, considering that this is just a formatting function, you could also create a custom filter:

```
angular.filter('bill', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ?  Number(input) / 100 : '';
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built in currency filter that you should consider using. This will use the system's locale too which is very handy. How you would use it is where you're outputting:

```html
<span id="billedAmount">{{enteredBillAmountNumber | currency}}</span>
```

If you need to use this in a controller, you can inject $filter and then use:

```js
var myFormattedAmount =  $filter('currency')($scope.enteredBillAmountNumber);
```